# Drill can not read parquet files from a Minio server

Tags: apache, amazon-s3, apache-drill, minio

The instruction:

https://blog.minio.io/query-minio-datastore-with-apache-drill-dcaf71d0cee5

Works without problems.

Also a query on for example JSON files works.
Only the query on parquet files does not work.

There are a few hints on the WWW. But they do not really seem conclusive and do not give a real solution.

Maybe someone here has a !!! Solution !!!

[2 Files in Minio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpv6a.png)

```
select * from samples.`product.json` limit 1 // Works

select * from samples.`nation.parquet` limit 1 // Doesn't work
```

Comment: It would be much better if you have posted an exception with which the second query fails. Otherwise it's hard to tell.

Comment: Error: SYSTEM ERROR: AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: null, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden

Comment: You might look at drillbit.log for more descriptive error message. Maybe file parquet file is not accessible?

Answer (score 0):

@Frank What version of Minio and Apache Drill are you using? I believe that the latest version of Apache Drill 1.13 should work.

Comment: I use the 1.13 Drill Version and the last Minio Version. 
The Cluster have 6 Zookeeper and 6 Drill Hosts.

Answer (score 0):

@Frank what is the Minio version and how did you start the Minio server?